# Create column with row object data and html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatables, angular-datatables

I have to create a custom column in my table, allowing me to perform actions and which html code should be generated according to the object that define the row.

I'm new to angular and i suppose i should use $compile but i'm not sure how.

column definitions:

```
vm.dtColumns = [
  DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('name').withTitle("Name"),
  DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null).withTitle("Actions").notSortable()
  .renderWith(function(data, type, full, meta) {
    //imported code from a previous version where the code was generated from a ng-repeat directive
    //project is the object, which can be found in the full parameter of the function
     var html = '<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#archiveProjectModal" type="button" class="btn btn-success col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1" ng-if="project.active"><i class="fa fa-check">&nbsp;&nbsp;</i>Archiver</button>'
     + '<a href="/project/{{project.id}}" type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1"><i class="fa fa-pencil">&nbsp;&nbsp;</i>Mettre à jour</a>'
     + '<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteProjectModal" type="button" class="btn btn-danger col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1"><i class="fa fa-trash">&nbsp;&nbsp;</i>Supprimer</button>'
     //what should i return ?
      return "?";
  }),
];
```

can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You should return the html string

```
return html
```

You will only need `$compile` if the returned html contain directives that should be invoked, like `ng-click` and so on. Do that in the `initComplete` callback :

```
vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
  .withOption('initComplete', function() {
     $compile(angular.element('#tableId'))($scope);
   })
})
```